# How to generate an x87 positive NaN value from C89 code?

Tags: c, ieee-754, c89, x87

I'd like to generate the positive [IEEE 754 32-bit float](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) NaN value with integer representation 0x7fc00000 from C89 code.

Here is how I do it with GCC (not conforming to C89):

```
float mynan(void) { return __builtin_nanf(""); }
```

Here is how I do it in C89 code (assuming sizeof(int) == 4 or sizeof(long) == 4):

```
float mynan(void) {
  union { float f; unsigned u; unsigned long ul; } fu;
  if (sizeof(unsigned) == 4) {
    fu.u = 0x7fc00000U;
  } else {  /* Assume that sizeof(unsigned long) == 4. It's always >=4. */
    fu.ul = 0x7fc00000UL;
  }
  return fu.f;
}
```

Here is how I test it:

```
float mynan(void);
typedef char assert_int_size[sizeof(int) == 4 ? 1 : - 1];
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  float f;
  union { float f; int i; } fi;
  (void)argc; (void)argv;
  fi.f = mynan();
  printf("0x%x\n", fi.i);  /* Prints 0x7fc00000 */
}
```

My question: is it possible to do it without `union` (or `NAN` in `<math.h>`, which is not C89) or `memcpy` (or `memmove` etc.), assuming x87 FPU and a nonoptimizing compiler (e.g. `gcc -O0`). I want the FPU to generate that NaN value for me as a result of some computation which I can trigger from C89 code.

I tried:

```
float mynan(void) {
  float f = 1L << 30;
  f *= f;  /* 2 ** 60. */
  f *= f;  /* 2 ** 120. */
  f *= f;  /* 2 ** 240, overflows 32-bit float, becomes INFINITY. */
  return f * 0.0f;  /* NaN. */
}
```

However, that prints 0xffc00000, which is the corresponding negative NaN value. How do I get the positive one?

I also tried:

```
float mynan(void) {
  float f = 1L << 30;
  f *= f;  /* 2 ** 60. */
  f *= f;  /* 2 ** 120. */
  f *= f;  /* 2 ** 240, overflows 32-bit float, becomes INFINITY. */
  return 0.0f - f * 0.0f;
}
```

This also returns the negative NaN.

I also tried:

```
float mynan(void) {
  float f = 1L << 30;
  f *= f;  /* 2 ** 60. */
  f *= f;  /* 2 ** 120. */
  f *= f;  /* 2 ** 240, overflows 32-bit float, becomes INFINITY. */
  return -(f * 0.0f);
}
```

This works with some compilers (e.g. `gcc -O0`), but not with others. One of the compilers generates code equivalent to `return 0.0f - (f * 0.0f)`, which keeps the sign as negative.

Comment: What about something like `unsigned u = 0x7fc00000U; float f; memcpy(&f, &u, 4);`?

Comment: @NateEldredge: That can also work, but that's similar to `union`. I've updated the question.

Comment: What's wrong with `memcpy` and `union`?

Comment: Since your existing `mynan()` is correct except for the sign, just negate it?  `return -(f * 0.0f);` seems to work.  Edit: Oh, but not when optimization is enabled.

Comment: Describing any of this as "portable C89" is strange because anything to do with internal representations is by definition non-portable.  All of this will simply be UB (or at best IDB) as far as C89 is concerned.  So exactly what set of implementations do you need to support?

Comment: @NateEldredge: Negating it works with `gcc -O0`, but it doesn't work with another compiler I'm (also) using, which generates x87 code equivalent to `0.0f - (f * 0.0f)` rather than `-(f * 0.0f)`. I've updated the question with these findings.

Comment: The most probable outcome is that it's impossible to generate the positive NaN value using x87 arithmetics only, and I'll end up using `union` or `memcpy`. However, there is a slight chance we've missed something.

Comment: @RaymondChen: `memcpy` and `union` are just fine as a final solution. However, I didn't like the many `if (sizeof(unsigned) == ...)` conditions (or equivalent `#if`s) they require, thus I started exploring alternatives. However, the current alternatives look even worse: they are compiler-specific and compiler-flag-specific.

Comment: If it's just `sizeof(unsigned)` that bothers you, you could use an `unsigned char[4]` instead.  `unsigned char buf[4] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x7f }; memcpy(&f, buf, 4);` should work on 16/32/64-bit implementations alike.

Comment: @NateEldredge: `unsigned char[4]` works except for endianness issues (e.g. on ARM), but at that point we've given up on x87.

Comment: Can you explain why it's important that the value be generated arithmetically?  It sounds like an XY problem.  You'd need code that several different compilers (which you haven't named) all compile into just the right combination of instructions, and that sounds basically hopeless to do reliably.

Comment: @pts, The approach taken assumes the endian of the `float` and the integer are the same.  Although this is common, it is not specified behavior and machines had been made with different endian.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    float nan = fabs(sqrt(-1.));
    printf("%f\n", nan);
    printf("%08x\n", *(unsigned*)&nan);
    return 0;
}
```

Output from clang, gcc, and Visual C compile and run:

```
nan
7fc00000
```

Your mileage may vary.

Comment: That's great, it works on all compilers I've tried, in all optimization settings.

Comment: As soon as I'm able to get a negative (or positive) NaN, `fabs(...)` can turn it to a positive NaN, no matter the C compiler optimization settings. `sqrt(-1.0)` is a reliable way of getting a NaN. `log(-1.0)` also works.

Comment: @pts `fabs()` is not as reliable as you think. `0. / 0.` gives `-nan` on some compilers, but  `fabs(0. / 0.)` also gives `-nan`! Go figure.